# Script to sync P4 code with a label

Tags: bash, shell, perforce, workspace

I'm writing a script to sync P4 code with an existing label using command "p4 sync @labelname". 
I have a network folder mapped as (S:) where i have the workspace "check".

The issue i'm facing is when i issue the sync command, it is creating a duplicate directory as "SUVHTV~2" 
in S: and updating the changes instead of updating in S:/check

Note: Workspace "check" is created using Perforce and Root is provided as (S:/check)

Comment: If the workspace Root is S:\check, it's unlikely that a sync command is going to be writing files to S:\SUVHTV~2.  Maybe you have a junction point that's redirecting file operations from one to the other?  Maybe you're using a different workspace spec from the one you think you're using?  Maybe it's something else your script is doing?  It's impossible to know which without more information; I'd recommend contacting Perforce tech support so they can help you debug.

Comment: yeah, i also assume it should write to S:\check, but it is not :(

Comment: Is it because a network folder is mapped here to S: ? When i do a "ls" at the root, it displays the workspaces "check" and "S:", the later being the duplicate workspace created, which in windows view seen as SUVHTV~2. P4CLIENT is set as check in my script before sync command.

Comment: I can't even speculate without seeing the workspace spec, the actual contents of the workspace... I don't even know what sort of environment you're operating in because "S:" is a Windows drive spec but "ls" is a Unix command.  Write support@perforce.com, stackoverflow tends to shut down back-and-forth comment threads and there's no way I can guess how to fix your script without a lot more back and forth.  Write support@perforce.com!  :)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like your environment variable for P4CLIENT is not set properly. Please explicitly set this variable in your script.

I am assuming you have cygwin/mks toolkit or some other unix-shell-on-windows software.

Try adding this line before you make the call to p4 sync command and see if it helps.

```
export P4CLIENT='check'
```